# ASP.NET MVC Context.User.Identity.Name == ""

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've run into an issue and I can't identify what the difference is between App 1 and App 2.  Both Apps execute the exact same line of code below from the `Session_Start()` in the Global.asax.  One app identifies the user correctly `DOMAIN\USER`, the other app simply returns `''`...

```
UserService.GetUserInfo(Context.User.Identity.Name.ToString());
```

Both apps have this in the Web.config for using Windows Authentication.

```
<authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
```

Comment: Is IIS configured with Windows Authentication in both sites?  Is Anonymous authentication turned off?

Comment: Both sites are setup to use Visual Studio Development Server.  The app that isn't working was changed at one point to use local IIS, but was changed back.

Comment: Click on the project, then click on the properties tab, does it say anonymous authentication is enabled?  If so, disable it.

Comment: Anonymous isn't even a Project Property.  I have Always start when debugging, project file, project folder.

Comment: <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>

Comment: The better solution is to move to using IIS Express, which won't have these kinds of issues.

Comment: That might need to be the case.  Just found the "default" behavior was acting like it wanted Anonymous, but I can't find where to turn that off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test it with IIS Express locally which supports Windows authentication. So in your web.config you must have the following:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

and in the properties of the project configure IIS Express to enable Windows Authentication:

[image]

`Anonymous Authentication` must be set to `Disabled` and `Windows Authentication` must be set to `Enabled`.